# PNG transparency in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, png, transparency

I'm adding an Image View in Interface Builder with a transparent PNG (A logo in the Navigation Bar) but the transparent pixels seems to render as white..

I searched for PNG in Interface Builder but no luck. any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the "Opaque" checkbox in the "Drawing" section of the view attributes is unchecked, and that the background has an opacity of 0.

Answer (score 1):

After you select your image in a UIButton in Interface Builder, you need to tell it to use a background with 0 opacity (alpha).