# .png file loads with a black background in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have moved .png images to my assets folder in Xcode. But, it appears to have a back background! Could anyone please let me know how can I remove the black background from the .png files? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this would be helpful, but I did find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700223/png-transparency-in-interface-builder

Sharing the link instead of copying the answer in case this is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @Torewin I unchecked the opaque button in my UIIMage attributes as mentioned in the link provided! But how can I make the background opacity to be 0? Thanks!

Comment: I believe they are referring to the UIImage that you add the image to. If you want to post the PNG image, I can see if I can reproduce the issue

Comment: @Torewin I have updated my question with the .png image as requested! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's working for me completely fine. Where does it show up as a black background? Is it in xCode folder? Assets.xcassets? Within a `UIImageView`? Are you programmatically assigning it to a UIImageView? To set the background to opacity: 0 - I think they are referring to setting `Background` to `Clear Color` if you're using the storyboard.

Comment: @Torewin It's showing a black background in my assets folder and when I am assigning it to an imageview in the storyboard!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224823/discussion-between-torewin-and-pressing-keys-24-7).